# Comparing feature extractors (or comparing aligned images)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'd like to compare ORB, SIFT, BRISK, AKAZE, etc. to find which works best for my specific image set. I'm interested in the final alignment of images.

Is there a standard way to do it?

I'm considering this solution: take each algorithm, extract the features, compute the homography and transform the image.

Now I need to check which transformed image is closer to the target template.

Maybe I can repeat the process with the target template and the transformed image and look for the homography matrix closest to the identity but I'm not sure how to compute this closeness exactly. And I'm not sure which algorithm should I use for this check, I suppose a fixed one.

Or I could do some pixel level comparison between the images using a perceptual difference hash (dHash). But I suspect the the following hamming distance may not be very good for images that will be nearly identical.

I could blur them and do a simple subtraction but sounds quite weak.

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: I have thousands of images to test. These are real world pictures. Images are of documents of different kinds, some with a lot of graphics, others mostly geometrical. I have about 30 different templates. I suspect different templates works best with different algorithms (I know in advance the template so I could pick the best one).

Right now I use cv2.matchTemplate to find some reference patches in the transformed images and I compare their locations to the reference ones. It works but I'd like to improve over this.

Comment: What kind of transformation are you talking about? Rigid? Affine? Non-linear? One way to validate is to manually determine some correspondence points, then check their distances after the transformation.

Comment: They are rigid transformations with perspective (with minimal warping sometimes), real world pictures of rigid bodies. I have thousands of images to align and I want to find what works best on average. Right now I'm using AKAZE and it works very well, SIFT was good too. But on some images I have problems and visually it looks like ORB or BRISK may find more useful features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it seems like the task is not to compare the feature extractors themselves, but rather to find which type of feature extractor leads to the best alignment.

For this, you need two things:

- a way to perform the alignment using the features from different extractors
- a way to check the accuracy of the alignment

The algorithm you suggested is a good approach for doing the alignment. To check if accuracy, you need to know what is a good alignment.

You may start with an alignment you already know. And the easiest way to know the alignment between two images is if you made the inverse operation yourself. For example, starting with one image, you rotate it some amount, you translate/crop/scale or combine all this operations. Knowing how you obtained the image, you can obtain your ideal alignment (the one that undoes your operations).

Then, having the ideal alignment and the alignment generated by your algorithm, you can use one metric to evaluate its accuracy, depending on your definition of "good alignment".

Comment: "Good alignment" means that subtracting certain regions of the aligned document from the reference template I should get a black image. But I suspect noise and other details will complicate things. I could first apply a blur/threshold but it seems a little fragile. Following your suggestion, would you compare the matrices or the images? How?

Comment: You can compare the matrices since the homography matrix should represent the inverse of the matrix you used to obtain the transformed image in the first place. Think of it as applying one homography, then opencv should give you the inverse homography. And there are some metrics that measure how similar are 2 matrices (such as frobenius norm) or you can derive something based on your needs. On the other hand, you can simply check if points in the transformed image are matched against points on the other image using a feature detector and/or some relevant points that you can reliably track.